# Trouble executing transaction in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having trouble getting a mysql transaction to work through PHP.  I'm fairly new to PHP and very new to mysql.

If I take the var_dump of $query and try to run it through phpmyadmin it works fine.

```
  $description = 
mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['description']);
  $query = 'BEGIN;
    INSERT INTO indiespark.tasks
(description, owner_user_id)
VALUES ("' . $description . '", ' 
. $user->user_id . '); 
SET @task_id = LAST_INSERT_ID(); 
INSERT INTO indiespark.projecttasks 
(task_id, project_id) 
VALUES (@task_id, ' . $project->project_id . '); 
COMMIT;';
 $result = mysql_query($query);
var_dump($query);
var_dump($result);
if ($result) {
    return viewproject();
} else {
    throw new Exception('database error');
}
```

Comment: You seem like someone willing to learn. Have a look at PDO or MySQLi. The mySQL extension you're using is ancient and outdated.

Comment: OK, I just looked at mysqli, so bear with me....

Replacing
    $result = mysql_query($query);
with:
    $result = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['db'], $query);

still doesn't work.

Comment: var_dump on $db shows every value as null?

Answer (score 1):

mysql_query doesn't support sending multiple queries in one call. Use separate calls.